# Selenium. Webdriver. Internet Explorer. Unable to evaluate //body XPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I hope somebody could point me in the right direction.  We're using Selenium Webdriver 2.28 with Internet Explorer version 8.

Our tests pass through the below method with the locator parameter is {By.XPath: //body}

```
private IWebElement WaitAndGetElement(By locator)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.DefaultWaitTimeSecs));
    var elementToWaitFor = wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(locator));

    return elementToWaitFor;
}
```

When the code hits that method.  The exception below is thrown.  This problem is quite reproducible with IE.  We do not encounter this error with Chrome or FireFox.

If anyone could point us in the right direction, we would be very grateful.

Many thanks.
Christian Clarke

OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException : The xpath expression '//body' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 156 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html

Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 2003', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.2', java.version: '1.6.0_31' Session ID: c72ebe1d-e7f0-4fdb-aab8-9f86b374a89a

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=internet explorer, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=8}]

Comment: I run into this issue from time to time with different XPath expressions and think it is a bug. But I haven't been able to reproduce it on a minimal testcase yet. I _think_ it happens when a `findElement()` is invoked at one particular moment during page load. If you can reproduce it reliably, please [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list) or just add it here, I'll gladly try to help!

Answer (score 0):

Not my favorite approach, but try changing your `XPath` expression to ".//body", it's likely that it will work with this *'fix'*.

Although i wouldn't advise using these locators on IE, since even on WebDriver they have proven to be slower, if possible, use CSS Locators.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the XPATH? Is it with Firefox XPATH Checker addon? If so I would suggest just using the XPATH with Firebug. That one seems to work the best IMO with IE. In Firebug once you have the element selected you can right click the element and choose Copy XPATH.

Comment: Just copy-pasting XPATH is not good enough. Usually FIREBUG hooks to the first found element with "id" attribute. You might want to start with some "class" attributes or etc. Also it's best to eliminate [NUMBERS]. In other words, be smart and use your head to create the best XPATH for your elements.